# Images/Grids not being displayed in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, html4

I am trying to debug an existing page having html4.01 as its doctype and trying to use this in html5 enable browsers..
What are the best steps to take while porting old websites into html5 enabled browsers.
Currently i am facing issues in displaying images that are being called upon in a function within a script...
JS are all outside the webpage and are being referenced...
A snippet is shown, here this replaces a radio button checked field with a selected not correct image/ selected correct image.

```
if (bAnswerOnceOnly)
{
//show selected not correct icon, and change cursor to default so that it shows that the check box
//is not clickable.                 
replacementHTML = "<img border='0' src='../cImages/sg_checki.gif' style='cursor:default'>";
}
else
{
//use this code instead of the above to reset graphic if we allow users to deselect the selected incorrect.
replacementHTML = "<img border='0' onClick='private_ResetGraphics(" + gMC[i].id +  ");' src='../cImages/sg_checki.gif'>";
}
```

Thanks,
Hrg

Comment: Can you provide additional details about your specific problem with images? It would be helpful if you posted some of your code in your question.

Comment: @BryanDowning: Here the functionality is to simply replace the radio button checked field with a image, the if the radio button checked is correct we display a correct tick image, if not v display a worng tick image. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IE you may be able to use the developer tool (F12) and change the Browser Mode/Document Mode to get your website to work.  e.g - you may need your browser mode in IE 9 Compatibilty View and the Document Mode in IE 7 Standards.  If you find this work you can then and you have a web server config file you can force this by adding the following -

```
<add name="X-UA-Compatible"` value="IE=7" />
```

or you can add a meta tag to each of your pages.

You can read more here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am able to get it to work in all IE's but im facing issues in Firefox and Chrome,I am getting getting Logical Error: Netscape currently not supported!!! Thansk again.